# Lotus notes 8.5 Inbox return to default sort and select next unread email

Tags: lotus-notes

My default Lotus Notes (v 8.5.2FP2) Inbox is sorted by date/time (newest at top).  I can then do the following steps:

- select a message (single click to select)
- click the 'Who' header: the sort order changes to 'by sender' (e.g. to see their previous messages).
- I can select and open a previous message by the sender.

All ok so far.  To return to the normal / default inbox view - i.e. sorted by date/time (newest at the top) I need to:

- click the 'Date' header (first time sorts in opposite order)
- click the 'Date' header again (this time sorts in correct order)
- click the 'Next Unread' navigation button to jump to the next newest message.

My issue is that I find it a bit of a pain to have to do these three clicks. Is there a simple 'Cancel sort' button?  If not, what can I do to get back to the default inbox view and sort order, in **one simple click?**

I suspect that I will need to create a custom button that sorts the inbox and navigates me to the next message.  There is a '@sort' function (which sorts a list) and a 'NavigateNextUnread' command, but I'm not sure how to perform the sort on the current inbox.

Comment: I have flagged this question to be moved to superuser.com instead (since this is not a programming question but a user question).

Comment: oops - you're right, I had originally thought I would need to do some coding but I don't think it will now - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to return to the default sort by clicking on the Who header (I can do that in my mail database).

Comment: Yes, but because of my step 3 (clicking a prev email) I'm still not at the top.  This does shorten it to two clicks however - one to reorder and another to move up.